# Change Source data on an existing Chart (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have an existing chart, named GRAFICO_PARETO.
This chart has a source data, let's say from A1 to G20 for example, and I want to change that range to another one but not from the front-end of Excel, but from vba.
The code I tried is like:

```
Dim datosGrafico As Range
Set datosGrafico = Range(Range("Z2"), Range("Z2").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))

 ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("GRAFICO_PARETO").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=datosGrafico
```

But there's something Wrong, because I get an '445' error on execution time in the last code line.

I'm doing this on Microsoft Excel 2016 in spanish.

Thanks for your support.

[image: CAPTURE]

Comment: I tried your code on some random data and both of the commands seem to work. Try to do a `debug.print datosGrafico.address` and check if it contains the desired range.

Comment: It shows: "$Z$2:$AC$5" which is correct.
Which Office version do u have? Because I saw it works on 2010 but not on my 2016... Thanks! I added an snapshot in case it helps!

Comment: Was the sheet containing the chart active when you ran the code?  `dataosGrafico` will get it's data from whichever sheet is active when the code runs and it will look for a chart on the same sheet.  Try fully qualifying which sheet everything's on.... `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects....`

Comment: What about the `datosGrafico = Range(Range("Z2"), Range("Z2").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))` ?
Is the sheet active where the data is placed?

Comment: yes, of course, always active, i tried deleting all  other sheets too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new "Pareto" Chart on Excel 2016 is not compatible with this. So I did a "homemade" "Pareto" merging a normal column and linear charts to have "permission" to use the same code... And works, as always did. I think Pareto is some kind of protected chart.